# Dart dynamic access to nested array

Tags: dart

I have a nested Map that's look like this :

```
{users: {1: {id: 1, name: Bill, date: 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000Z}}}
```

I want access to the name

```
array["users"]["1"]["name"]
```

This is working fine. But I want to do it "dynamically", like something :

```
final path = "users,1,name";
array[path];
```

Is there a way to do that in Dart ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this way:

```
final path = 'users,1,name';
final parts = path.split(',');
print(array[parts[0]][parts[1]][parts[2]]);
```